# Error parsing JSON api response - numerical array

Tags: json, parsing, numeric

I am trying to parse value from JSON api response in POSTMAN, but the key i need to parse starts with numerical.

Part of response:

```
"data": {
   "354a24d506af956a0ccf14444b18da38834eabbd": very good,
}
```

so using:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setGlobalVariable("poziomoceny", jsonData.data.354a24d506af956a0ccf14444b18da38834eabbd);
```

gives me error message:

```
an identifier or keyword cannot immediately follow a numeric literal
```

i tried using:

```
postman.setGlobalVariable("poziomoceny", jsonData.data.(354)a24d506af956a0ccf14444b18da38834eabbd);
```

and also tried to change it:

```
var po = "354a24d506af956a0ccf14444b18da38834eabbd";
postman.setGlobalVariable("poziomoceny", jsonData.data.po);
```

which does not either.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
jsonData.data[354a24d506af956a0ccf14444b18da38834eabbd]
```

Comment: doesn't work either. them brackets...

Answer (score 0):

the escape that actually works was:

```
postman.setGlobalVariable("poziomoceny", jsonData.data["354a24d506af956a0ccf14444b18da38834eabbd"]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).